# Can the default value of a Recoil atom be an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

Can I set the default value of a Recoil atom to be an object?

e.g.:

```js
export const currentUserState = atom({
  key: 'currentUserState',
  default: { name: '', email: '', userId: null },
});
```

And then set it with:

```js
import { currentUserState } from '../atoms/atoms';

const setUserState = useSetRecoilState(currentUserState);
setUserState(name: 'John', email: 'foo@bar.com', userId: getRand());
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It is allowed. Recoil atom state can be an object.
You have initialized the atom correctly, but when you set the atom you have to pass an object since the state is object.

Initialize the `currentUserState` atom

```js
export const currentUserState = atom({
  key: 'currentUserState',
  default: {name: '', email: '', userId: null}
});
```

and then set the atom state as follows

```js
import {currentUserState} from '../recoilstate/atoms';

const setUserState = useSetRecoilState(currentUserState);

setUserState({
  name: 'John', 
  email: 'foo@bar.com', 
  userId: getRand()
});
```

Comment: How about merging previous userstate with spread operator and change part of the propery with a new value? How to change the state in a selector instead using setState?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Recoil atom can be an object.

I have written this code, which you can see below in the working demo.

```
 const changeValue = () => {
    setUserState({ name: "John", email: "foo@bar.com", userId: Math.random() });
  };
```

**Working Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]